# UIButton and IBAction

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

I have a custom UIButton on storyboard and I have wired the IBAction

```
    - (IBAction)homeButtonPressed {
NSLog(@"home");
```

}

to check to see if it works. When I press the button, it highlights and everything so I know the button is being pressed..but the NSLog doesn't print.....

User Interaction is enabled btw....

Comment: Check in your xib that you have connected the method to your desired button.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you connected the method with the button event UIControlEventTouchUpInside in the storyboard? If yes try to delete the button, create it again and connect to the method... ( not being able to see your project this is the quickest way to solve i think)

Comment: yes UIControlEvenetTouchUpInside is connected in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

The

```
    (id)sender
```

Is not the problem it is needed only to get the event sender but the method has to work the same without it...